# Sending an array of string in a request made with rest-client gem

Tags: ruby, request, rest-client

I am creating a gem to implement the [Calendly API](http://developer.calendly.com/docs/getting-started) and I need to make a request like

```
curl --header "X-TOKEN: <your_token>"
     --data "url=https://blah.foo/bar&events[]=invitee.created"
     https://calendly.com/api/v1/hooks
```

to create a webhook.

As you may see, `events` is passed as an array of strings and this is indicated by the `[]`.

I am trying to use `RestClient::Request#execute` to send this request, but I don't know how to pass this array of strings in this case.

I tried

```
RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post,
                            url: @uri,
                            params: { url: url,
                                      events: "invitee.#{type}"
                                    },
                            headers: { "X-TOKEN": "#{@api_key}" })
```

but then I am not sending an array as the API expects.

I also tried

```
RestClient::Request.execute(method: :post,
                            url: @uri,
                            params: { url: url,
                            'events[]': "invitee.#{type}" },
                            headers: { "X-TOKEN": "#{@api_key}" })
```

but it didn't work either. I got a bad request error and nothing else.

How should I build my request in this case?

Comment: have you tried `events: ["invitee.#{type}"]` this should be serialized appropriately

Comment: Not yet, but I'll try it now @engineersmnky.

Comment: It worked, @engineersmnky, thanks. If you post as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Posted for visibility** (previously answered in comment)

`RestClient` will appropriately serialize a native ruby `Array` for you meaning

```
events: ["invitee.#{type}"]
```

will be serialized into `events[]=invitee.created` where `type == 'created'`. This will work for an `Array` with multiple values too.

```
events: ["more","than","one"]
```

will be converted to `events[]=more&events[]=than&events[]=one`.

Finally it also handles an other data types inside an `Array` such as another `Hash`

```
events: [{first_name: 'Zaphod', last_name: 'Beeblebrox'}]
```

will become `events[][first_name]=Zaphod&events[][last_name]=Beeblebrox`